# How to correct the indentation for this line of code?

Tags: python

I'm doing some homework and I seem too have screwed up somewhere. The invalid syntax is appearing in line 8 and I'm assuming its an indention issue. Is there a way to correct this with out rewriting this?

```
def solve(puzzle,row=0,col=0):
    if puzzle[row][col]>0:
        next_row,next_col=get_next(puzzle,row,col)
    if next_row is None:
        return puzzle
    else:
        solve(puzzle,next_row,next_col) 
    else:                                              # line 8
         options=get_options(puzzle,row,col)
    if not options:
        return None
    else:
        for i in options:
            new_puzzle=copy_puzzle(puzzle)
            new_puzzle[row][col]=i
            result=solve(new_puzzle)
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

The second `else:` is supposed to end this branch of the recursion, causing the function to backtrack and consider different values for previously filled-in cells.

Comment: What was your intention with that `else`. What is it the "else" of? Please describe your thinking when you wrote that part of the code.

Comment: a few things: lines 4-7 should be indented another level and lines 10-18 should be indented to align with line 9

Comment: You have two elses in a row, that's not okay

Comment: You shouldn't copy code for your homework! Also, read documentation or examples for if else control loop - https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-if-else-elif-statement/

Comment: In what conditions do you want `solve(puzzle,next_row,next_col)` to run versus `options=get_options(puzzle,row,col)`? You haven't defined what conditions you want `options=get_options(puzzle,row,col)` to run in.

Comment: Use a __linter__! If you use VSCode, Ctrl+Shift+P and select 'Python: Select Linter'. I use flake8, there are several, VSCode lists them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should have probably looked like this:

```py
def solve(puzzle,row=0,col=0):
    if puzzle[row][col]>0:
        next_row,next_col=get_next(puzzle,row,col)
        if next_row is None:
            return puzzle
        else:
            solve(puzzle,next_row,next_col) 
    else:
        options=get_options(puzzle,row,col)

        if not options:
            return None
        else:
            for i in options:
                new_puzzle=copy_puzzle(puzzle)
                new_puzzle[row][col]=i
                result=solve(new_puzzle)
            if result is not None:
                return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an else statement after another else statement with the same indentation.
You can only write an else statement after an if or elif.

The correct answer seems to be this:

```
def solve(puzzle,row=0,col=0):
    if puzzle[row][col]>0:
        next_row,next_col=get_next(puzzle,row,col)
        if next_row is None:
            return puzzle
        else:
            solve(puzzle,next_row,next_col) 
    else:
        options=get_options(puzzle,row,col)
        if not options:
            return None
        else:
            for i in options:
                new_puzzle=copy_puzzle(puzzle)
                new_puzzle[row][col]=i
                result=solve(new_puzzle)
            if result is not None:
                return result
```